# PyCharm Debugger Lines Are Out Of Sync With Reality

Tags: debugging, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I'm using Django Rest Framework 3.5.4 and Pycharm Professional 2016.3.1. Incidentally, I have PyCharm configured to use a virtualenv inside a local vagrant box.

When I step through the DRF code with the debugger on, I can see that it is stepping through blank lines, and the variables in the debugger don't match those in scope (pictured here is `rest_framework.response.Response.rendered_content()`):

[image: breakpoint on blank line]

Here's another example that shows how variables in scope in the debugger don't match the single variable passed in. Also, note how the breakpoint is clearly on a docstring:

[image]

This is not the first time I have seen this in PyCharm; while viewing the library source usually works, occasionally I will see a mismatch between the source caches and what is being executed.

My question is: how can I correct this behavior? I have tried blowing away my virtualenv and then rebuilding it and reassociating it with PyCharm. I have also tried `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` and in this particular case neither have helped.

EDIT:

I thought I had solved this issue by removing all of the ~/Library/Caches/PyCharmXX/remote_sources/* files, re-invalidating the caches, restarting PyCharm, and re-associating the remote interpreter with the project. The next time I tried debugging the same file, I was given a screen to select the sources. I clicked **auto-detect** and noticed that two versions were available:

[image: select local file for the file from remote host]

I did a diff between the two that were available, and there was no difference. Also, the number of bytes and the modification times were the same in each file:

```
pnore at pnore-mbp in ~/Library/Caches
$ ls -l PyCharm2016.3/remote_sources/974253138/308149114/rest_framework/serializers.py
-rw-r--r--  1 pnore  HBS\Domain Users  60495 Mar  7 16:56 PyCharm2016.3/remote_sources/974253138/308149114/rest_framework/serializers.py

pnore at pnore-mbp in ~/Library/Caches
$ ls -l PyCharm2016.3/remote_sources/974253138/-328085538/rest_framework/serializers.py
-rw-r--r--  1 pnore  HBS\Domain Users  60495 Mar  7 16:56 PyCharm2016.3/remote_sources/974253138/-328085538/rest_framework/serializers.py

pnore at pnore-mbp in ~/Library/Caches
$ diff PyCharm2016.3/remote_sources/974253138/308149114/rest_framework/serializers.py PyCharm2016.3/remote_sources/974253138/-328085538/rest_framework/serializers.py
[no output]
```

I arbitrarily chose the latter one, and subsequently, debugging line numbers appeared to match up for that file. I believe the problem was that a previous version of PyCharm had associated that path file with a cached old version of the library. I do not know why invalidate caches on its own did not solve the issue.

**Unfortunately, the association does NOT remain in PyCharm across debugging sessions**. This means that the every file needs to be re-associated for every debugging session; something is clearly wrong.

Comment: It still seems something far to get solved: see this [jetbrains issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39432)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, two files with the same path and the debugger was using the wrong one, though in my case the files did differ slightly.

The fix was as follows on Windows with PyCharm 2017.2.3:

1. Exit PyCharm.
2. Remove folders leftover from previous versions of PyCharm. In my case there was both `.PyCharm2017.2` and `.PyCharm2017.1` folders.
3. Restart PyCharm.
4. Debug again, select auto-detect when prompted to select the correct source.

Comment: Where are the folders you are refering to?

Answer (score 0):

set "path mappings" in the debug configuration

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PyCharm on Mac. Had the same issue. Saw I had about a half dozen of these folders going back to 2016. Deleted all but the latest and it fixed the issue.