# PyCharm debugger step over skips a line?

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I am using PyCharm as Python IDE and debugging tool. Just upgraded to 2020.1.2.

Occasionally, while stepping over in debugger, it skips a line in a function which normally should be executed. I tried to a lot of fix it, like re-editing the function, format the code etc., without any luck. Only one route that is promising is to define another function as proxy only to call this problematic function, but this is really what I am not going to do because that makes the code so clumsy. If I copy this function into another new .py file and debugging stepping over it, it can be quite normal. I have got no clue what goes wrong except the chances are PyCharm has a bug.

Anybody same with me? Any solutions? thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem but never cared to find a fix for it, though. Quick google search leads to this SO post: [PyCharm Debugger Lines Are Out Of Sync With Reality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42651430/7851470). Take a look at the issues on their tracker as well: [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?_ga=2.80069207.110456129.1592587903-1776642265.1589148785&q=debugger%20skips%20lines%20project:%20PyCharm%20sort%20by:%20Created%20desc)

Answer (score 5):

It might be related to [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41621).

Try adding this environment variable to your run configuration:

```
PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO
```